# Constructing a sequence in $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$ (in the product topology) with no convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I want to know whether my proof is correct:

I claim that the sequence of indicator functions $x_n = 1_{A_n}$ (where $A_n = \{n\}$) does not converge in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$ and has no convergent subsequence. Indeed, if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is non-empty then there exists $x \in A$, so the basic open set defined by $B = \displaystyle{\prod_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}} U_{\alpha}}$ where $U_\alpha = \{1\}$ if $\alpha = x$ or $\alpha = c(x+1)\doteq d$ (where $c(x)$ stands for the ceiling function) and $U_\alpha = \{0,1\}$ everyhere else obviously contains no tail of the sequence $(x_n)$ (since $1_{A_n}(d) = 0 $ for all $n > d$ and so $1_{A_n} \notin B$ for all $n > d$ -it doesn't contain one tail, therefore it doesn't contain any other-). An almost identical argument applies to show that it no subsequence converges.

Is everything okay? Could I improve anything here?

**EDIT: it's all wrong. I'll try to fix it.**

Comment: Your example is not correct. Your sequence converges to the zero function in the product topology.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see... I was under the misconception that it had to converge to an indicator function, I see now that is indeed not the case. Thanks.

Comment: It does, the zero function is the indicator function of the empty set.

Comment: I think your set $B$ is not open - in infinitely many indices it is not all of $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Christoph now that you mention it I can see that it's the indicator function of the empty set, but I'm not sure whether you're implying that any sequence which converges has to converge to an indicator function.

Comment: The elements of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$ are by definition indicator functions of subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh of course. Goddamn, I'm slow today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is wrong. I'll use that $C:=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, so that $\{0,1\}^C$ is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{R}$.

On the space $C$ we have the projections $p_n$ mapping each element (a sequence of "bits") to its $n$-th component. On $\{0,1\}^C$ we have the projections $\pi_c$ for each $c \in C$ mapping $f \in \{0,1\}^C$ (functions from $C$ to $\{0,1\}$ to its value $f(c)$, and the product topology has the property that it is the smallest topolgoy making all $\pi_c, c \in C$ continuous, and also that $f_n \to f$ in $\{0,1\}^C$ iff $f_n(c)=\pi_c(f_n) \to \pi_c(f)=f(c)$ for all $c$ (so convergence is pointwise convergence).

Now define the sequence $f_n$ by $f_n(c)=\pi_c(f_n)=p_n(c)$ for all $c \in C$.

This sequence does not have a convergent subsequence: suppose it had, say $f_{n_k}, k = 0,1,2,$ converging to $f \in \{0,1\}^C$.

Define $c': \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ by $c'_{n_{2k}} = 1$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ and $c'_m=0$ for all other $m$ not of that form. Then $c' \in C$.

Consider $\pi_{c'}(f_{n_k}) = p_{n_k}(c')$ for all $k$: for even $k$ its value is $1$, for odd $k$ its value is $0$. So $\pi_{c'}(f_{n_k})$ does **not** converge to any point in $\{0,1\}$ so certainly not to $\pi_{c')(f)=f(c')$, as it ought to. This is a contradiction: no convergent subsequence can exist.

Comment: I had to do so many other exercises today that I forgot to try and fix my original post. Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it.